# Windows 10: mail account accessible in notification

Tags: windows-10, email

Just few minutes back, I clicked the notification icon at the bottom right corner of the screen (Windows 10 Pro on HP Probook 440) and was shock to find that I was able to see my hotmail emails. This is the first and only time I am able to see my email this way.

I have used only one way to access this email account, by manually entering used id and password on a web browser, mostly Firefox. And I don't allow the email account to stay logged in.

How to prevent Windows 10 from doing this? Is Cortana doing this? I don't like Cortana (and never use it) but not to the extent to spending time looking for a way to disable/delete it. Now, it's probably the time to do it.

Comment: More likely that Hotmail is Microsoft rather than Cortana. Look in your Windows 10 mail accounts. Did Microsoft set up Hotmail there?   Perhaps you have Office and Outlook as well and Outlook is a better app.

Comment: Have you used the Windows Mail app on your computer for your hotmail account?

Comment: @ harrymc Not I can remember.

Comment: @John Windows 10 mail is not linked to any accounts. However, I might have deleted any links while panic. Can't remember it anymore

Comment: Go to Start, Settings, Cortana and make sure all settings are off. See if that stops Cortana from interfering